# Where does Quine's method in propositional logic originate?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

[Hein](https://books.google.com/books?id=JHlJNHzgB1MC&pg=PA408&lpg=PA408&dq=Quine%27s+method+discrete+structures+logic+and+computabilit&source=bl&ots=ZbwqhfFtw-&sig=ACfU3U0AZSEiHOL90dpa5MOo0NLS3TDL1g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjo7OCB8ejxAhVyUt8KHc4JBBoQ6AEwBnoECBkQAw#v=onepage&q=Quine%27s%20method%20discrete%20structures%20logic%20and%20computabilit&f=false) (407-408) states that Quine's method "...uses [these](http://vh216602.truman.edu/agarvey/cs291/section6.2.pdf) (14) properties together with basic equivalences to determine whether a wff is a tautology, a contradiction, or a contingency." The idea is to substitute atoms in a propositional logic well-formed formula with true or false, and reduce it down to T or F which determines its truth meaning. I know how to do it, but the issue is: where does this *come* from? I've searched high and low across the internet to see where this originates, but all sources point back to the Hein book. Did he invent this? If so, why is it called Quine's method?

Comment: [Quine (1938)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2267505)

Comment: “I’ve searched high and low across the internet …”  But not looked in Quine’s books?

Comment: Hein didn't invent it.  I remember reading something similar in A. N. Prior's book on Formal Logic form the 1960s.  It's not impossible that it got used before Quine... maybe Tarski used when he was Lesniewski's doctoral student and checking to see that some formulas were tautologies, I don't know.  Quine perhaps gave the first somewhat precise formulation of the method and make it more noticable by using something of the idea in his completeness proof.  Though, it's a lot like equational methods in abstract algebra.